# Drop cap style weirdness

Tags: css

I applied .drop_cap class to the first letter of every post, such as this: http://www.mossoreviews.com/193-safe-er-grip-bath-and-shower-handle-review/

It's all right in Firefox13. However, in Chrome17 and IE9, not only the first letter is .drop_cap styled but also the second letter is styled exactly the same, as if the second letter is also en-wrapped in

```
<span class="drop_cap"></span>
```

But it actually is NOT. Any idea how this is happening and how I can fix this?

Comment: Drop cap like it's hot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your CSS declaration is applying the drop cap styles to both your span and the paragraph:

```
.drop_cap, .entry > p:first-of-type::first-letter
```

This line should only be one or the other.

Either remove the span around your first character and take advantage of the `:first-letter` CSS property, or remove the `.entry > p:first-of-type::first-letter` from your selector.

Comment: The real problem seems to stem in apparent differences between browsers' handling of the `::first-letter` pseudo-element. If you notice, there's an image in the first `span` just before `span.drop_cap`. I recall from an earlier question by the same OP regarding this, and it looks like it's only causing more issues. Funky.